# Text in SVG's foreignObject not selectable

Tags: text, svg

I have a `SVG` and want to display some text within that. Due to the limited text formatting options available in `SVG` I've read that it can be recommended to use HTML for text instead. Thus, inside of the `SVG` whenever I want to show text I have a `foreignObject` and within that a text `p`.

So the structure is: `SVG -> foreignObject -> p`

Works well so far! However, I cannot select the text within the `p` with the mouse. Is there any workaround?

EDIT:
Looks like it works in an easy example as shown in the answer below, but for some reason it does not work in this structure here.
[image: This is the actual structure]

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me on Firefox. If you're using that create a testcase, if you're not then raise a bug on the non-working UA.

Comment: I'm also using firefox, latest version.

Comment: foreignObject needs a capital O and also requires height and width to be attributes and not css styles (as in my answer), if that doesn't fix it please provide runnable code like I did and not just a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="80px">
  <foreignObject width="200px" height="80px">
    <html style="font-size:30px">
      <p>Select me</p>
    </html>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, that's strange. This easy examples also runs fine here. I've updated my question with the actual structure I have on my project where it doesnt